# React npm start causes react web app to start the same project from any directory (even when that project is deleted)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

*I'm sorry this is a little bit long..I'd really appreciate any help! (And if this is a repeat qn, I'd really appreciate it if you'd let me know! Thank you!!)*

There is probably a problem with my npm globally. The first time an error occurred when I tried to use node-sass in my react app, my code editor flagged this error:

```html
Fangs-MacBook-Pro:react_frontend fangran$ npm start

> react_frontend@0.1.0 start /Users/fangran/Documents/microservices-test/react_frontend
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack-dev-server was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/fangran/Documents/node_modules/webpack-dev-server (version: 3.10.3) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack-dev-server" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if /Users/fangran/Documents/node_modules/webpack-dev-server is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls webpack-dev-server in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack-dev-server.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react_frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react_frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/fangran/.npm/_logs/2020-08-31T02_45_12_620Z-debug.log
```

So I followed these suggested instructions and the error was still there. Then, running `npm ls webpack-dev-server`, I got

```
react_frontend@0.1.0 /Users/fangran/Documents/microservices-test/react_frontend
└─┬ react-scripts@3.4.3
  └── webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
```

The weird thing is, running `npm ls webpack-dev-server` in any other directory resulted in it showing the webpack-dev-server version of another already deleted project directory (nba-tutorial has been deleted from my Documents folder). Here's some examples:

```
Fangs-MacBook-Pro:microservices-test fangran$ npm ls webpack-dev-server
nba-tutorial@0.1.0 /Users/fangran/Documents
└─┬ react-scripts@3.4.1
  └── webpack-dev-server@3.10.3

Fangs-MacBook-Pro:microservices-test fangran$ cd ..

Fangs-MacBook-Pro:Documents fangran$ npm ls webpack-dev-server
nba-tutorial@0.1.0 /Users/fangran/Documents
└─┬ react-scripts@3.4.1
  └── webpack-dev-server@3.10.3
```

I then changed my npm config prefix to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` by running

```
fangran@Fangs-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm config set prefix /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

But nothing got fixed. At this point i'm pretty confused about what's going on. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node as well but things still remained the same. May I ask how I can successfully run npm start in my microservices-test/react_frontend directory please? And what's going on?

Thank you for your time reading this!

Comment: Could this be a path issue? Is it possible it’s running the wrong `react-scripts` install?

Comment: delete `/node_modules` on `/Users/fangran/Documents/node_modules` delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder,then in your project folder reinstall

Comment: @rayhatfield Thank you so much for your reply! I'm not sure...how can i fix that? Or find out if it is?

Comment: @LiuLei Thank you for suggesting that! But I've actually already tried that, and there's no node_modules folder in my /Users/fangran/Documents

Comment: actually this error is because two different version of the `webpack-dev-server`.  according to those error info `/Users/fangran/Documents/node_modules/webpack-dev-server (version: 3.10.3) ` your Documents folder have a version 3.10.3 ,but you needed is version 3.11.0.

Comment: is there a global package `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: Run `which react-scripts` to see which one it's running.

Comment: @LiuLei yeah...that's the thing, there's actually no node_modules directory under /Users/fangran/Documents. Also, the error still happens even when I tried uninstalling webpack-dev-server. So I don't think there's a global webpack-dev-server package.

Comment: @rayhatfield I tried running which react-scripts and nothing got returned :/

Comment: temporarily solution: Create a .env file in the root directory of the project and add this line `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` inside the file

Comment: run `npm run env|grep PATH` to see what the path environment variable is set to when running an npm script.

Comment: (sorry for the spam @rayhatfield) it returns this 

```PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/fangran/Documents/microservices-test/react_frontend/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin```

when I run this in the /microservices-test/react_frontend directory.

Comment: @LiuLei Sorry for my silly question, but may I ask if this will fix my global npm issues o.o? I suspect i messed something up with the global npm thing but im not sure what and how to resolve it.

Comment: actually this issues always appeared in which one folder have multi-project each project have it's own `package.json` file. so it's easy to happened version confilct. but it's not effect your global  `npm`. if really effected your global npm just uninstall and reinstall npm @Ran Fang

Comment: @LiuLei hmm i actually tried that as well, uninstalling and reinstalling npm didn't help either :/

Comment: well, if you create a new project is there still the same problem ?

Comment: @LiuLei yeapp, same error - i think its a global issue (something was set somewhere but i just have no idea how to fix it)

Comment: try this command `npm config set prefix /usr/local`